# how come my c++ code gives 2 different outputs in ideone and codeforces custom test?

Tags: c++, compilation

ideone:https://ideone.com/Ba3Nw7

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int i,n,b25,b50,temp;
cin>>n;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin>>temp;
    if(temp==25)
        b25++;
    else if(temp==50)
    {
        if(b25>0)
        {
        b25--;
        b50++;
        }  
        else
        {
            cout<<"NO";
            return 0;
        }

    } 
    else if(temp==100)
    {
        if(b25>0 && b50>0)
        {   
            b25--;
            b50--;
        } 
        else if(b25>2)
            b25-=3;
        else
        {
            cout<<"NO";
            return 0;    
        }
    }
}
  cout<<"YES";
  return 0;
}
```

the test case tried is:
2
25 100
the output on ideone is "NO" which is the correct answer but on the codeforces custom test it gives a "YES",why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One very glaring mistake I can see is not initialising variables `b25` and `b50`.

In your code, you are continuously incrementing and decrementing the two variables, and therefore, your answer goes wrong every time.

I would suggest:

```
int i,n,b25=0,b50=0,temp=0;
```

You might be getting a right or a wrong answer because arbitrarily any value can get stored in `b25` and `b50`. Sometimes it may satisfy the `NO` condition, and at other times, a `YES` condition.

---

Had your variables been static or within file scope, they would have been initialised as 0. However, your variable is locally defined, hence its value will be indeterminate, invoking undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the variables `b25`, `b50` uninitialised, but guessing from your code you assume them to be initially zero.

Their initial value can currently differ from run to run, so putting it a second time on one of those platforms may give more different results. (Unless ideone uses BSD or something where memory is initially zero by default)